# Update document if value there is no match

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

In Mongodb, how do you skip an update if one field of the document exists?

To give an example, I have the following document structure, and I'd like to only `update` it if the `link` key is not matching.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56e9978732beb44a2f2ac6ae"
    },
    "domain": "example.co.uk",
    "good": [
        {
            "crawled": true,
            "added": {
                "$date": "2016-03-16T17:27:17.461Z"
            },
            "link": "/url-1"
        },
        {
            "crawled": false,
            "added": {
                "$date": "2016-03-16T17:27:17.461Z"
            },
            "link": "url-2"
        }

    ]
}
```

My update query is:

```
links.update({
    "domain": "example.co.uk"
    },
    {'$addToSet':
        {'good':
            {"crawled": False, 'link':"/url-1"} }}, True)
```

Part of the problem is the `crawl` field could be set to `True` or `False` and the date will also always be different - I don't want to add to the array if the URL exists, regardless of the `crawled` status.

**Update:**
Just for clarity, if the URL is not within the document, I want it to be added to the existing array, for example, if `/url-3` was introduced, the document would look like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56e9978732beb44a2f2ac6ae"
    },
    "domain": "example.co.uk",
    "good": [
        {
            "crawled": true,
            "added": {
                "$date": "2016-03-16T17:27:17.461Z"
            },
            "link": "/url-1"
        },
        {
            "crawled": false,
            "added": {
                "$date": "2016-03-16T17:27:17.461Z"
            },
            "link": "url-2"
        },
        {
            "crawled": false,
            "added": {
                "$date": "2016-04-16T17:27:17.461Z"
            },
            "link": "url-3"
        }

    ]
}
```

The `domain` will be unique and specific to the link and I want it to insert the `link` within the `good` array if it doesn't exist and do nothing if it does exist.

Comment: Why are you using the `upsert` option? Do you intend to insert a new document if there is no match? Also Is "domain" unique?

Comment: Yes `domain` will be unique to the `link` - I think I may be using it incorrectly, I want it to insert the link within the array if it doesn't exist and do nothing if it does exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is to find if there is any document in the collection that matches your criteria using the [`find_one`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) method, also you need to consider the "good.link" field in your filter criteria. If no document matches you run your update query using the [`update_one`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) method, but this time you don't use the "good.link" field in your query criteria. Also you don't need the [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator as it's not doing anything simple use the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) update operator, it makes your intention clear. You also don't need to "upsert" option here.

```
if not link.find_one({"domain": "example.co.uk", "good.link": "/url-1"}):
    link.update_one({"domain": "example.co.uk"}, 
                    {"$push": {"good": {"crawled": False, 'link':"/url-1"}}})
```

Comment: That works! Though I needed to add the upsert option back in so other wise it doesn't work. I'll assume you can do these in bulk due to them being separate requests?

Answer (score 1):

in your find section of the query you are matching all documents where

```
"domain": "example.co.uk"
```

you need to add that you don't want to match

```
'good.link':"/url-1"
```

so try

```
{
    "domain": "example.co.uk",
    "good.link": {$ne: "/url-1"}
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question to hopefully be more clear as it's adding a new document rather that adding to the array

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not correct by saying the only way to do it is using `findOne` first.

You can do it in a single db call by using the [aggregation pipelined updates](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) feature, this allows you to use aggregation operators within an update, now the strategy will be to concat two arrays, the first array will always be the "good" array, the second array will either be `[new link]` or an empty array based on the condition if the links exists or not using `$cond`, like so:

```
links.update({
  "domain": "example.co.uk"
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "good": {
        "$ifNull": [
          "$good",
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "good": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$good",
          {
            "$cond": [
              {
                "$in": [
                  "/url-1",
                  "$good.link"
                ]
              },
              [],
              [
                {
                  "crawled": False,
                  "link": "/url-1"
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
], True)
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eJmAWk53FA0)